# The method 'data' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: data()

Tags: flutter, dart

When I try to put the value added to Firebase into the Droppdown button, I get the following error

The method 'data' was called on null.Receiver: nullTried calling: data ()

I think the cause of the error is that I can't call the value from Todo.dart to post_page.dart.

Using debag, todolist is null in post_page.dart.

I would appreciate it if you could answer.

post_page.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:habit_boddy/component/post/task_add_button.dart';
import 'package:habit_boddy/utils/constants.dart';
import 'package:habit_boddy/view/common/components/drop_text.dart';
import 'package:habit_boddy/view/common/components/post_caption_part.dart';
import 'package:habit_boddy/view/post/page/Todo.dart';
import 'package:habit_boddy/view/post/page/detail_page.dart';
import 'package:habit_boddy/view/post/page/picture_page.dart';
import 'package:habit_boddy/view/post/page/task_setting.dart';
import 'package:habit_boddy/view_models/post_view_model.dart';
import 'package:habit_boddy/view_models/todo_view_model.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'confirm_dialog.dart';


class PostPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PostPageState createState() => _PostPageState();
}

class _PostPageState extends State<PostPage> {
  final _captionController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _captionController.addListener(_onCaptionUpdated);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _captionController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<ToDoViewModel>(
      create:(_) => ToDoViewModel()..getRealtime(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
          actions: [
            ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('Post'),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: Colors.orange,
                  onPrimary: Colors.white,
                ),
                onPressed: () => showConfirmedDialog(
                    context: context,
                    title: "Post",
                    content: "May I post?",
                    onConfirmed: (isConfirmed) {
                      if (isConfirmed) {
                        _post(context);
                      }
                    }))
          ],
        ),
        body: Consumer<ToDoViewModel>(builder: (context, model, child) {
          final todoList = model.todoList;
          return DropdownButton<Todo>(
            items: todoList.map((todo) =>
              DropdownMenuItem<Todo>(
                value: Todo(title: todo.title),
                child: Text(todo.title),
              )
            ).toList(),
          );
        }),
        floatingActionButton:
            Consumer<ToDoViewModel>(builder: (context, model, child) {
          return FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              await Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TaskSetting()),
              );
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }

  _onCaptionUpdated() {
    final viewModel = Provider.of<PostViewModel>(context, listen: false);
    viewModel.caption = _captionController.text;
    print("caption: ${viewModel.caption}");
  }

  void _post(BuildContext context) {
    final postViewModel = Provider.of<PostViewModel>(context, listen: false);
  }
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final postViewModel = Provider.of<PostViewModel>(context);
  return Container(
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 3,
                  child: Container(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                        child: DropText(),
                      ),
                      height: 230),
                ),
                Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 155.0),
                      child: TaskAdd(),
                    )),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                  child: DetailPost(),
                ),
                height: 270),
            Row(
              children: [
                PicturePage(),
                postViewModel.imageFile == null
                    ? Container()
                    : Container(
                        height: 60,
                        width: 60,
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          child: PostCaptionPart(
                            from: PostCaptionOpenMode.FROM_POST,
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Todo.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:habit_boddy/view_models/todo_view_model.dart';

class Todo {
  final ToDoViewModel model;
  String title = "";
  DateTime createdAt;
  Todo({DocumentSnapshot doc,  this.title, this.model, this.createdAt}){
    this.title = doc.data()["title"];
    final Timestamp timestamp = doc.data()['createdAt'];
    this.createdAt = timestamp.toDate();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this line is causing the error.

```
              DropdownMenuItem<Todo>(
                value: Todo(title: todo.title),
```

You're calling doc.data() in the Todo constructor without passing the doc variable, hence calling .data() on a null variable. You should instead get the title first, then pass it to the constructor when instantiating the Todo object.

If you really need to pass the doc variable, say if you need it for something else, make it required in the constructor and assert that it is not null.

```
Todo({@required DocumentSnapshot doc,  this.title, this.model, this.createdAt}) :  assert(doc != null){
...
}
```

You should look into Dart null safety as well, which would help to avoid this type of issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After revising,"Failed assertion: line 11 pos 91: 'doc != null': is not true. "comes out. Is this error a kind of null safety?I'm having trouble resolving this error.I would appreciate it if you could answer.

Comment: You're getting that error because the doc variable in the constructor is null. You need to either pass in the snapshot when you create the Todo object, `Todo(doc: doc, title: todo.title)` or change the constructor to not use the snapshot.

Comment: I'm sorry many times. I'm wondering how to pass a snapshot. I added this code `DocumentSnapshot doc;`if  I change the constructor to not use the snapshot, Should I change Document Snapshot type to a different type?

Comment: Take some time and read through the classes section of the [Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#classes)